# Error while playing video

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, mediaelement

I know this is very easy stuff but I cannot make it work.
I added video file (.wmv) to my project and tried to play it with a media Element. But I always have an error that is : `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : HRESULT - 0x80004005`

Here is the code :

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="MyMobileApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyMobileApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement x:Name="MyMediaElement" Height="640" Width="400" Source="GOPR0179.wmv" MediaFailed="MediaElement_MediaFailed"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Can you please help me?

Here is the code behind :

```cs
private void MediaElement_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ErrorMessage);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to play other file (codec)? Is your file build action set to Content? Are you able to play that file on the phone by default video app?

Comment: Yes I tried avi and mp4 files. It doesn't work either. And Yes my files have the BuildAction set to content

Comment: It now works with one file only. The video was not playable. Trying to fix it

Comment: Problem fixed. The path of the video was not good.